# Check how many different values there are and return them

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to check how many rows with different value for ( in this case ) "subject" are.

For example: In my database I have 5 rows.

**subject of row 1** = 1
**subject of row 2** = 5
**subject of row 3** = 3
**subject of row 4** = 1
**subject of row 5** = 8

I want to have a return like: 1,5,3,8 where as you can notice the 1 is not showed twice.

Does anyone maybe know a way to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: keyword DISTINCT or use a GROUP BY

Comment: Can you explain how you get 5 for the second row? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks @Dagon I will look if it will help ;)

Comment: @halfer The values don't matter I think. It's just random number given to a subject like Mathematics.

Comment: @gibberish That's the problem I don't have anything for this. I just couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to return the deduplicated values:

```
select distinct subject from yourTable;
```

If you want to know how many times a subject appears in your table:

```
select subject, count(subject) from yourTable;
```

If you want to count the *unique* subject values:

```
select count(distinct subject) from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `distinct` keyword:

```
select distinct subject from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY subject
```